# If $P(B|A) > P(B)$ and $P(C|B)>P(C)$, then prove or disprove $P(C|A) > P(C)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have this question in intro to probability:

> If $P(B|A) > P(B)$ and $P(C|B)>P(C)$ then prove or disprove $P(C|A) > P(C)$

It is also given that $A, B,$ and $C$ are events with probability greater than $0$. I have tried to do the following:

$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A|B) \cdot P(B)}{P(A)} > P(B)$$

by Bayes

$$\implies P(A|B) > P(A) \text{ because } P(B)>0$$

I did the same for the other expression, but I can't seem to be able to connect the formulas.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @WilliamM. Thanks for the quick reply! Not sure what you meant though. Could you please explain what x,y are and how do I implement it's probability

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was not very helpful. I misread your equation since they weren't typed in MathJax. Note that the relation $P(E \mid F) > P(E)$ is symmetric in $E,F$ and it is perhaps more convenient to write it as $P(E \cap F) > P(E) P(F).$ In this way of writing, it is much more suggestive that the result needn't be true. Now it would be time to play with events until you find the right (counter)example.

Comment: I think the events in a two throwing of a die will work: $A$ is "first number is 1", $B$ is "both numbers are 1" and $C$ is "both throws are the same". Then $B$ is contained in both $A$ and $C$ which makes the hypothesis trivially true and yet $A$ and $C$ are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a roll of a six-sided die, and define the events
$$ A = \{ 1\}, C = \{2\}, B = \{1,2\}.$$ Then $P(B)  = 1/3, P(B|A) = 1, P(C) = 1/6, P(C|B) = 1/2.$ But $P(C|A) = 0 < P(C)$.

Of course, the opposite can happen too - take $A = \{1,2,3\}, B = \{1,2\}, C = \{1\}.$